# How can I get GHC Core output via stack?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack, stackage

How do I get a `stack build` command to dump the GHC Core?
I've tried this, to no avail:

```
stack build :hello_world --ghc-options '-ddump-simpl'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to clean before, or force recompilation via the stack option `--force-dirty` and ghc option `-fforce-recomp`.

The files are dumped somewhere around `.stack-work/dist/.../build/hello_world/hello_world-tmp/`.

Comment: That "where did my dump files go?" thing is super-annoying. Do you know if it works to add `-dumpdir=mydumps` to the GHC options, or does stack override that?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, stack parses ddump-hi to get info for recompilation detection.  Ideally, it could only redirect that particular ddump